# Angular2 with Signalr two way binding is not working

Tags: c#, angular, signalr, angular-cli

My server constantly sending data every 2 second. and I have SignalR to listen "addMessage" event (it works) ,for example: I want to get name from server, and it shows correct, but I want to update name value to 0 after I clicked check button. but my console.log shows nothing changed.any helps will be appreciated.
app.component.ts code below:

```
 ngOnInit() {

  let o: IConnectionOptions;
  let conx = this._signalR.createConnection();
  conx.status.subscribe((s) => console.warn(s.name));
      conx.start().then((c) => {

          let listener = c.listenFor('addMessage');

          listener.subscribe((msg:any) => {
              this.messages = msg;
              this.name= msg.data[41].value;
              console.log(this.name);

          });
      });
```

};

My HTML code:

if name = 1 shows click button and name

```
           <div *ngIf ="name==1 ;else pic1">  
                 <button (click)="ng-model = name='0'" >
                               Check
                        </button>

                        <div>
                             <tr>
                                 <th>name:</th>
                                 <th>{{name}}</th>
                             </tr> 
                        </div>
                </div>

                <ng-template #pic1>
                else here         
                </ng-template>
```

my server code(c#):

```
//default sending 1 until name value change to 0    
  if (string.Equals(name, "name"))
                {
                    if(string.Equals("0",value.PlanStringValue))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(value.PlanStringValue);
                        result.Add(name, value);
                    }
                    else
                        value.PlanStringValue = "1";
                        result.Add(name, value);
                        Console.WriteLine(value.PlanStringValue);
                }
```

Comment: Did you mean "not working?" Otherwise it sounds like a success story. successstories.stackexchange.com

Comment: it was typo ,sorry

Comment: What is about `(click)="name = 0"`?

Comment: I wish it could send back 'name =0' once I clicked "check" button .